# Flux producer one-to-many

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm trying to transform a Flux with Reactive. The Flux is typed with a POJO that contains a list. I would like to re-map my Flux to a new Flux that contains all the children of all the POJOs.

It's like using the `map` method of a `Flux`, but instead of producing 1 item per each input, it should produce 0 to n items. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)` ?

```
Flux.just(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"))
            .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

If you mean some projection of the POJO property, you can simple go ahead and call `.map()` for that nested `Flux` in the `flatMap`.